# Concat dataframes in Pandas with different frequency removes the timezone

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm trying to merge 2 time series with Pandas. The first one (**df1**) is a Series and the second one (**df2**) is a DataFrame.

```
df1
2016-07-05 11:30:00+01:00    -100.81
2016-07-05 11:31:00+01:00    -99.34
2016-07-05 11:32:00+01:00    -95.09
..............
..............
2016-07-05 11:45:00+01:00    -83.62
2016-07-05 11:46:00+01:00    -1.57
2016-07-05 11:47:00+01:00    21.01
..............

df2['column1']
2016-07-05 11:30:00+01:00    -79,45
2016-07-05 11:45:00+01:00    -51.11
2016-07-05 12:00:00+01:00    -12.67
2016-07-05 12:15:00+01:00    15.21
..........
```

The indexes of **df1** and **df2** are DatetimeIndex with the timezone set as (*datetime64[ns, Europe/London]*)

```
print df1.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-05 11:30:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 11:31:00+01:00',
               '2016-07-05 11:32:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 11:33:00+01:00',
                ...
               '2016-07-19 14:30:00+01:00', '2016-07-19 14:31:00+01:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/London]', length=1358, freq=None)

print df2.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-05 11:30:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 11:45:00+01:00',
               '2016-07-05 12:00:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 12:15:00+01:00',
                ...
               '2016-07-19 14:30:00+01:00', '2016-07-19 14:45:00+01:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/London]', length=1358, freq=None)
```

I need the average of the values of **df1** each 15 minutes, so I resample the Series as follow:

```
df1 = df1.resample('15Min').mean()

print df1.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-05 11:30:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 11:45:00+01:00',
           '2016-07-05 12:00:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 12:15:00+01:00',
            ...
           '2016-07-19 14:30:00+01:00'],
           dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/London]', length=1358, freq='15T')
```

Now I want to merge the series so I run:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

The problem is that I loose the timezone for some reason, and the result is:

```
df
2016-07-05 11:30:00+01:00    -100.81    -79,45
2016-07-05 11:45:00+01:00    -83.62     -51.11
2016-07-05 12:00:00+01:00    -12.67     -12.67
2016-07-05 12:15:00+01:00     15.21      15.21
...........
```

but the index looses the timezone

```
print df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-05 11:30:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 11:45:00+01:00',
               '2016-07-05 12:00:00+01:00', '2016-07-05 12:15:00+01:00',
                ...
               '2016-07-19 14:30:00+01:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', length=1358, freq='15T')
```

Since I have a DataFrame , I've tried to use the join also, but the result is the same.

My questions are:

- Is there any way to merge the time series without loosing the timezone?
- Does anyone know why this happen? Is it related with the **freq** attribute in the Datetimeindex?

I know that one solution would be to set the timezone again after the concat(), but I would like to know if there's a way to merge the time series without loosing the timezone.

PS I found this [link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3232) but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: this smells like a bug, check if it's an outstanding issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: For me it works nice. What is your pandas version?

Comment: My version is 0.18.1

Comment: I think the bug is the same reported here https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12898 ... more precisely in this issue the timezone is dropped when aggregating, but it might be closely related ... they also mention this issue https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10668  ... @EdChum do you think i should report the bug? or is the one I linked already the one?

Comment: it refers to `groupby` in those cases, but I'd just post an issue, the developers will decide if it's a different issue (but may have same root cause) or not

Comment: This issue it's the one: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3232 ... which by the way it's the one I post in the question ... PS @jezrael which version do you have?

Comment: I use pandas 0.18.1 and python 3 under win 7

Comment: Hmmm, I test it only with your sample, so it works nice. But if dataframe is larger, I think it cannot works too.\